# How to display two different translation in one view - Rails ?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, internationalization, rails-i18n

I have an app with two translation: :pl and :en.
I want to send email in both languages (one view file)

Something like that:

```
=t(".my_translation_key", :en)
=t(".my_translation_key", :pl)
```

instead of

```
-I18n.locale = :en
=t(".my_translation_key")

-I18n.locale = :pl
=t(".my_translation_key")
```

is there any way ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just send the `:locale` option:

```
= t(".my_translation_key", :locale => :en)
= t(".my_translation_key", :locale => :pl)
```